# Mysql can't use mysql if condition in order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to write a select like this

```
if(`order` > 0)
    Order BY category_id, arder
if(`order` = 0)
    Order BY id
```

But in  this select does not work

```
SELECT *  from post 
ORDER BY if(`order` > 0,  ( category_id, `order`) ,  id)
```

Comment: Why not just `Order BY category_id, \`order\`, id` ?

Comment: as default order is 0 , and this case will show 0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3... items

Comment: but i need that was result 1,2,3... 101,... 0,0,0
also I cant except items with order is 0

Comment: (
SELECT *  from post 
where `order` > 0

ORDER BY  category_id ,`order`  
)

UNION

(
SELECT *  from post 
where `order` = 0
ORDER BY  id  
)

Comment: and this select returns incorrect ordering 2,3,4 ...9, 13,14, .. 18 ,10,12

but the are working correctly part of part

Answer (score 0):

"If" is an expression returns a value, I don't think you can use it to change the "order by" statement itself.

You can try something like this:

```
select *, case when order>0 then category_id else 0 end cat_id, id
from post
order by cat_id, order, id
```

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!!!! 
I just add case when `order` > 0 then category_id else 111110 (as cat_id= 0 does not have ordering will first show 0 items , but in 111111 case first will show exists ordering )